# Drupal 6: getting random data from database

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, random, drupal-6

I spend few hours at google, but cant find :/

is it possible to get a random data from database with Drupal 6?

appreciate helps!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want random data, there is no point in getting it from the database, you should generate it PHP instead.

To answer your question:
If you want to get a random row from your db you can do: (MySQL only)

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

But you still have to specify the table.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Views? You can set what content to pull, limit to 1 result, and tell it to sort it randomly.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to get random nodes? Random Users? Random comments? The question is a little vague. Views can support a random ordering and random filtering. . . so you can get back your content in either a random order or a random selection. Does that help?